# Parse: push notification to specific device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, parsing, notifications

I want to send a parse notification to a specific device by the object id.

The API Call from PHP is:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
$appId = //app id
$restKey = // rest key
$target_device = 'TARGET_INSTALLATION_OBJECT_ID_HERE';  // using object Id of target Installation.

$push_payload = json_encode(array(

"where" => array(
    "objectId" => $target_device,
),
"data" => array(
    "alert" => "This is the alert text."
)

));

// curl exec...
```

How can I get the TARGET_INSTALLATION_OBJECT_ID_HERE by javascript (because i am using phonegap)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For android you can use this phonegap plugin: [ParsePlugin](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin)

For iOs I can´t help you, since Im not currently working with it